# uncaught SoapFault Exception : failed to load external

Tags: soap-client, iis-10, php-7.3

I'm very new in PHP+SOAP, and now I need to pass some data to the given url using it, unfortunately I've receive this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/bms/server.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/bms/server.php?wsdl" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bms\client.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bms\client.php(12): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://10.1.65....') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bms\client.php on line 12.
```

according to my research on google, almost all of those solution is to enable **Soap, xml (with libxml library installed), and openssl**, and its all have been turn on and I'm unable to access/view the server code, due to some restriction.

what am I missing?

below are my client code

```
<?php

//client.php

$opt = array(
    'trace' => true
);
echo "1";
$client = new SOAPClient('http://localhost/bms/server.php?wsdl', $options);
echo "2";
//////////
$msg = "hello World";
$subj = "greating";
$recv  ="user@email.com";
$sentType = 2;
$sendDate = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$createdBy = "admin@email.com";
////////
$client->DoSendMessage(
    ['MsgContent' => $msg, 'Subject' => $subj,'Receiver' => $recv,
    'SendType' => $sentType,'SendDate' => $sendDate,
    'CreatedBy' => $createdBy]);
?>
```

work environment : 
IIS 10,
PHP 7.3

thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the wsdl url is blocked. Try contacting the vendor regarding this or maybe get an actual wsdl file from them. The first step before hitting a SOAP API would be to check if the wsdl file opens an external XML structre